# ReactDom createPortal child components not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

I tried to create a dropdown menu with createPortal() because of visibility problems due to the stacking context, but the child components are not working as they should. The OperationButton has an onConfirm event.

```js
createPortal(
  <div
    className={`widgetActionsMenu`}
    style={{ position: 'alternative', top: '27px' }}>
    {allowedOperations.map((pseudoOperation) => {
      const [operation, disabled] = pseudoOperation.split(':');
      return (
        <OperationButton
            disabled={!!disabled}
            key={operation}
            operation={operation}
            itemId={props.itemId}
        />
      );
    })}
  </div>
  ,
  document.querySelector(`.flowChartActionLevel`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actuall assigning it to a ref solved the problem, it now finds the child elements and their properties.

```
const portalRef = React.useRef(null);
```